# Upgrade GLIBC on Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, qt, debian, glibc, beagleboneblack

When I try to run my app on BeagleBone I get following error:

> /home/debian/Desktop/myapp: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6:
>   version GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by
>   /usr/local/qt4.8.2-armhf/lib/libQtCore.so.4)
>   /home/debian/Desktop/myapp: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6:
>   version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by
>   /usr/local/qt4.8.2-armhf/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4)

How to upgrade `GLIBC` to version I need, or how to fix these 'not found' errors? How to check if I have GLIBC installed?

is it **glibc -v?**

Comment: `apt-get update` then `apt-get upgrade` now are you sure even the latest Wheezy glibc version has GLIBC_2.15 symbols ?  You can check with `objdump -p /lib*/libc-*.so` maybe fixup the exact path to the file you see.  I you can not find `GLIBC_2.15` in there but only older then I guess you need to upgrade the entire distro to something newer than wheezy.

Comment: glibc is ALWAYS installed with Wheezy.  The package is https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libc6 to confirm installation of a package and its current version try `apt-cache show libc6`

Answer (score 2):

To find the version of your libc, you might run the `libc.so` shared object (which strangely is also executable... unlike most other shared objects), e.g. on your Raspberry Pi:

```
/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
```

To upgrade your libc, the pragmatically realistic way is to **upgrade your entire** Respberry Pi **distribution** (since almost every software depend upon the libc).

Perhaps installing Linux on your laptop and cross-compiling Qt5 and the software your want to use on it for the Raspberry Pi might be less painful.

Comment: I have BeagleBone Black.

Comment: @Zola: Congratulations. So what? Do you intend to compile everything on your Raspberry Pi? It would be painful and slow.

Comment: I don't want to compile anything on my BBB, just to cross-compile code on my VM and run that executable file on my BBB.

Comment: Debian Wheezy is old. If you want to cross compile new applications, please use Debian 8 Jessie : Has libc6 (glibc) version 2.19, and will have the object `GLIBC_2.15` included in the lib files : https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libc6

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch what can go wrong if I just upgrade GLIBC version and not the whole distribution, for example with Qt App?

Comment: Anything could go wrong, and actually will. GLIBC is the cornerstone base of every software. If you want to upgrade, upgrade your entire distribution.